# Странная ошибка tkinter '_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "pyimage1" not defined'

Tags: python, tkinter

Я не понимаю и не могу исправить ошибку tkinter

> _tkinter.TclError: bitmap "pyimage1" not defined

Код

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
root.resizable(False, False)

c = Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
c.pack()

filename = ImageTk.PhotoImage(master=c, file="photo.png")

l2 = Label(root, text='Состояние: ничего не происходит', fg='black', padx=2, height=1, width=40, bitmap=filename) #<- ошибка здесь
l2.place(x=0, y=80)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Я смотрел на ответы других пользователей stackoverflow на английском, но мне не помогло

Comment: filename = ImageTk.PhotoImage(master=c, file="photo.png") - точно работает? Попробуйте там указать полный путь к файлу.

Comment: @Михаил_Алексеевич не работает, пожалуйста уточните

Comment: что за файл photo.png? Почему у Вас есть уверенность, что Ваш код его находит?

Comment: @Михаил_Алексеевич Потому-что, он лежит в папке с этим кодом, и здесь не в этом проблема, он открывается, я проверял

Comment: То, что он там лежит - не гарантирует его доступности при открытии таким  способом.

Comment: @Михаил_Алексеевич я указал полный путь, и проблема та же

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `bitmap=filename` используйте параметр `image=filename`. Bitmap'ы - это другого типа картинки (которые создаются командой `ImageTk.BitmapImage()`).